# C# Set dropdown list default value

Tags: c#, list, dropdown

I'm setting default value of dropdown list in Form.Designer.cs, but when I change position of this or even another object in the design window, this line disappears and dropdown list doesn't display any value.

```
        this.comboBox2.DropDownStyle = System.Windows.Forms.ComboBoxStyle.DropDownList;
        this.comboBox2.Enabled = true;
        this.comboBox2.FormattingEnabled = true;
        this.comboBox2.Items.AddRange(new object[] {
        "beam center",
        "force application"});
        this.comboBox2.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(402, 258);
        this.comboBox2.Name = "comboBox2";
        this.comboBox2.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(121, 21);
        this.comboBox2.TabIndex = 45;
        this.comboBox2.SelectedIndex = 0;
```

[image]

Do you know how could I fix that? Thanks in advance.

Comment: There is a big warning at the top of `Form.Designer.cs` whoch says not to edit the file directly.  Move the line to the `Shown` event

Answer (score 0):

Move it out of the designer generated code and into a place like Form_Load

Comment: How can I open Form_load window ?

Comment: When you are in the designer view you can double click on your windows form, it is the default event for forms. Alternately, from the properties pane for the form you can change to the events views and double click on the event you would like to associate with

Comment: In the event list there is no load and show event. Maybe it's not avaible for this object.

Comment: You may not be on the properties for the form, as those two events are very much available for form objects

Comment: Oh now it's clear. Thank you a lot and sorry for such basic questions.